# Lightbox2 fb:comments img id

Tags: url, image, facebook-social-plugins, lightbox2

How can I get photo id for facebook href? that each photo has its own comments?
in .lb-caption the photo link is through php inside, would in just about java in the href of "fb:comments" have

Thanks for the help!

**lightbox.js**

```
 if (typeof this.album[this.currentImageIndex].title !== 'undefined' && this.album[this.currentImageIndex].title !== "") {
    $lightbox.find('.lb-caption').html(this.album[this.currentImageIndex].title).fadeIn('fast');
        $lightbox.find('.lb-facebook').load('facebook.php');
```

**Facebook.php**

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="{markus.luttinger}"/>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<fb:comments href="" num_posts="2" colorscheme="dark" width="460"></fb:comments>
<script>FB.XFBML.parse();</script>
```